# When to act on PayPal subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

See here: https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside

There are 6 different notifications and I've never fully understood when I should use each one.

For example, when there is a sign up notification, does that mean I have the money?
Also, which notification do I remove their account on? If they pay for a month, then cancel their membership halfway through, but I still keep the money, what notification will be sent on day 30?

Basically, I need to know when to create their account and when to delete their account. There must be an easy way to this mess.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signup is not a payment.  It's just a new profile that gets created.  You'd get a separate IPN for any payment that actually occurs related to a signup (subscription profile), so if your profile is configured to charge the first payment right away you'll get 2 IPN's right away:  subscr_signup, and subscr_payment.

If they cancel their account you would get the subscr_cancel notification right away when that happens so you can update your database accordingly.

Same thing for the end of term.  That's when you'll get a subscr_eot notification, so you'd kill their account in your system when that happens, too, or display a way for them to renew or whatever you wanna do in those cases.

Comment: Does subscr_eot get called at the end of the subscr_cancel month?